# 19.10 leaves monitor powered down on resume from suspend. 19.04 worked fine with the same hardware

Tags: updates, suspend, 19.10

After upgrading a Dell Inspiron 3670 with a Samsung SF35 monitor to 19.10, when resuming from suspend, I can hear the disk spinning up.  The monitor powers down at standby, but does not come back up. The OS ignores the wireless keyboard and mouse at resuming; I have tried with a wired keyboard and the result is the same.

Everything worked fine on the same hardware in 19.04.

How do I get 19.10 to completely resume from suspend and recognize the keyboard and mouse?

@heynnema

blkid

/dev/sda7: UUID="c67eb87d-f1ab-439c-a359-3c782e0d520f" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a2b783bb-7bb9-4d3f-8b09-7deec77ff742"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="ESP" UUID="FE56-5444" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="037356e9-4f8f-493e-8484-7e2f040d6a39"
/dev/sda2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="1b2ee557-0e12-4305-9bc0-aa3dd9c177cc"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="OS" UUID="7226F71426F6D855" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="122f9428-8ae9-4f08-89b9-9eeb48cac03b"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="WINRETOOLS" UUID="A878FD4A78FD17B0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="880330aa-c1b9-4417-a756-5a82b550f4f1"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="Image" UUID="045AFDC45AFDB292" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="69577312-f43c-4aa9-a2dc-62d1cdf821ba"
/dev/sda6: LABEL="DELLSUPPORT" UUID="D0526AE6526AD130" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="39bb44ec-1747-4a1f-9854-804588152ec4"
/dev/sda8: UUID="7a1f04f8-bf12-48ad-b762-9f46bde6e3fa" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="2780d164-1c1e-45b1-8191-2f799e0a17e3"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="RLHSG2T" UUID="F85E3A095E39C0E4" TYPE="ntfs" PTTYPE="atari" PARTUUID="235e0b3d-01"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"

## /etc/fstab: static file system information.

#

## Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a

## device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices

## that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).

#

## / was on /dev/sda7 during installation

UUID=c67eb87d-f1ab-439c-a359-3c782e0d520f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

## /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation

UUID=FE56-5444  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1

## /home was on /dev/sda8 during installation

UUID=7a1f04f8-bf12-48ad-b762-9f46bde6e3fa /home           ext4    defaults        0       2

free

```
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
```

Mem:           11Gi       3.3Gi       4.9Gi       597Mi       3.3Gi       7.3Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi

/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw

cat: /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume: No such file or directory

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `free -h` and `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`.

Comment: Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.